# Openrefine: How do I delete multiple rows by a specific column value?

Tags: openrefine

I have about 200 rows of different starbucks coffee drinks and the firs column is calories with certain values that have "-" as opposed to a number. Would it be possible to delete all of the rows that have a value "-" in the calories column all at once?

Answer (score 0):

You can select the affected rows by either a [text facet](https://docs.openrefine.org/manual/facets#text-facet) or a [text filter](https://docs.openrefine.org/manual/facets#text-filter).

To delete the selected rows you can use the "All" dropdown left of the data columns via "All" => "Edit rows" => "Remove matching rows".